# Excel VBA - How to duplicate / move an Hyperlink?

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I'm creating a workbook to manage my folders and files, I already have created an **hyperlink for each file and folder**, but I wanted to **move them to another column afterwards**.

After some research, I found that it wasn't possible to directly move an hyperlink, so **find the code below to duplicate hyperlink and then delete the old one**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to move (duplicate then delete) all hyperlinks :

- in defined range (here `A1:C30000`),
- to one column on the right (`Set RgDst = RgSrc.Offset(0, 1)`),
- take the text of the new cell as Text to Display for the hyperlink
  (`, , , RgDst.Text`)

---

```
Sub HyperlinkMoveTest()
    Dim aSheet As Worksheet 'Sheet Handle
    Dim hLink As Hyperlink  'Hyperlink Handle
    Dim RgDst As Range     'Destination Cell
    Dim RgSrc As Range     'Source Cell

    'Set a Handle for the working sheet
    '---------------- edit possible ----------------
    Set aSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


    '------------------ edit possible ------------------
    For Each hLink In aSheet.Range("A1:C30000").Hyperlinks
        'Fetch the cell address of the source Hyperlink
        Set RgSrc = hLink.Range
        'Set the Destination Cell address based on the Source Cell address
        '---------------- edit possible ----------------
        Set RgDst = RgSrc.Offset(0, 1)


        'Load the Destination Cell with the Hyperlink
        '---------------- edit possible ----------------
        '--- Args : Anchor, Target Address, [Address within workbook], [Screen Tip], [Text to display]
        aSheet.Hyperlinks.Add RgDst, hLink.Address, , , RgDst.Text

        'Delete the previous link
        hLink.Delete
    Next hLink

    Set aSheet = Nothing
    Set rngSrc = Nothing
    Set rngDst = Nothing
End Sub
```